# Buildings on the Google Maps Android SDK

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Buildings on the map begin to appear at x17 zoom and in 3d mode, in google maps app, they appear at a much smaller zoom and also in 2d mode. How to achieve this?

Comment: API and the native maps app are different products managed by different teams at Google. I'm afraid you shouldn't expect the same behavior in both.

Comment: @xomena maybe you right

Answer (score 0):

for zooming (modify zoom with any float number ):

```
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlan,zoom))
```

then you have to move the camera for you location :

```
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlan))
```

for map type :

```
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
```

there are types (GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL and GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE)
you may want  to read this 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map